# UWP: Do not zoom media transport controls for a media player element inside a scroll viewer

Tags: c#, windows, zooming, media, uwp-xaml

I want to add zoom functionality for media  player element(UWP C#) . I placed MediaPlayerElement inside a scroll viewer and zoom functionality is working. But inbuilt  media transport transport controls is also getting zoomed and scrolled. I want the media transport controls to be fixed. I tried setting margin and height and width property for transport control. But they do not seem to work. How do I avoid zooming and scrolling of transport control bar

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer 
                Name="ScrollViewerMain"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                MinZoomFactor="1" 
                ZoomMode="Enabled"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="314" Margin="427,186,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="730" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" 
                VerticalScrollMode="Auto" ManipulationMode="System" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mpe" Stretch="Uniform" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, ElementName=ScrollViewerMain}"
                MaxHeight="{Binding Path=ViewportHeight, ElementName=ScrollViewerMain}"
                   />
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScrollViewer`'s zoom is an overall behavior, and its zoom is equivalent to the distance you look at the object.

*Objects appear small from a long distance, but the size of the object itself is constant.*

When you use `ScrollViewer` to zoom, it will inevitably change the whole.

So if you plan to manually zoom on the `MediaPlayerElement`, there are two options:

1. Get the increment of user operation through `PointerWheelChanged` or `ManipulationDelta` event, and change the `width` / `height` of `MediaPlayerElement` by increment.

   When the size of the control is changed directly, the icon of `MediaTransportControls` will keep the original size.

   Regarding gestures, this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions) may be helpful.

---

2. Do not display `MediaTransportControls` of `MediaPlayerElement` itself, rewrite a transport control yourself, independent of `ScrollViewer`, and overlay on top, like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  MinZoomFactor="1" 
                  ZoomMode="Enabled">
        <MediaPlayerElement Stretch="Uniform"
                            AreTransportControlsEnabled="False"
                            />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <MyTransportControls VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         />
</Grid>
```

In this way, when the `ScrollViewer` is zoomed in, it will only affect the `MediaPlayerElement` and will not affect the `TransportControls`.

---

**Update**

By communicating with the engineer, we reached a conclusion, The touchpad sends `Pointer` events rather than `Manipulation` events. You can handle pinch input from the touchpad with the `PointerWheelChanged` event.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both your suggestions.
1. I registered for manipulation delta events as suggested in the below documentation (implement pinch and zoom for media player element)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#pinch-and-zoom-video
I am not getting manipulation delta events for scale gestures(tried mouse scroll, pinch gesture and stretch gesture in touch pad). But I am getting events for translate gestures.Am I missing something. 
(I tried this in the same xaml shared earlier by me after removing scroll viewer)

Comment: 2.I tried implementing custom transport control.This seems to work. But then I have to implement functionality of what mediaTransportControls is doing now(like auto hide,seek bar...).To avoid this,I tried creating a derived transport controls as said in this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls
and linked derived media transport controls with media player element as below.
mpe.TransportControls = derivedmtc;  
The above causes an ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.' Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, About Manipulation, please show your code that we can analysis your problem. Regarding the custom Transport control, if you derive it from `MediaTransportControl`, you can reduce the amount of code, but you must put the derived control in `<MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>`, so you cannot separate the transport control.

Comment: Thanks. I have shared my sample code : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AizIJTHyJpeMbBZybyJPe-Xrta0?e=Pnl0KX
Regarding derived controls, I cannot use them to avoid zoom of transport controls(as it is part of  <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>). Instead I have to write my own transport controls from scratch. Is my understanding right

Comment: Hi, I tested your code. On the touch screen, it works fine (pinch finger zoom). However, when using a touchpad, it does not recognize it as zooming due to its internal recognition mechanism. You can try to verify this with the help of a `simulator` of Visual Studio to simulate a two-finger touch on the screen

Comment: Thanks. I tested using a simulator.Touch screen works. So does this mean I won't get a manipulation delta events  when doing scale gestures using a touch pad ?

Comment: Does your touchpad support multi-touch? I am consulting an engineer on this matter

Comment: Yes, my touch pad supports multi touch. Infact when I use pinch gesture using touch pad in a scroll viewer , items inside scroll viewer gets zoomed.

Comment: Hi, I'm communicating with the product team on this question, and I will update my answer if there is new information.

Comment: Hi @karthikvr, Sorry for the late reply. At present, the touchpad problem has been judged as a bug and has entered the processing flow. It will be fixed in a later system version.

Comment: Hi @karthikvr , By communicating with the engineer, we reached a conclusion, this behavior is by design. The touchpad sends pointer events rather than Manipulation events. You can handle pinch input from the touchpad with the `PointerWheelChanged` event from the `MediaPlayerElement`.